# Creating two value range slider from Angular material native component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need a two value range slider for my app, however none of the packages that I've looked at on NPM etc are 100% suitable for what I need. The Angular Material slider is the most suitable, however it doesn't allow for two values to be used on a single slider.

To get around this, I've had an idea of placing one slider on top of the other, to give the impression of one slider with two values. This works well, and has a smooth behaviour which is one of the requirements that I wanted my slider to have.

However, I would also like to add a bar in between the two slider thumbs, so that the selected range is highlighted and visible. The native slider does have this, but since it only allows one value the highlight starts from 0 and extends to the value of the slider.

Instead I want to have the highlight between the upper and lower values of the thumbs on the slider. But I have no idea how to add this to it. So I was wondering if someone could help me out. I'm not entirely sure if I'd need to add a new element on top of the bar that adjusts to the size between the two thumbs or if I'd have to do something different.

Alternatively if anyone knows how to make NGX-slider allow a smooth step like the angular material slider that would be the best solution and I'd love to hear it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-slider/ngx-slider

https://angular-9-material-starter-5ueh7p.stackblitz.io

Code so far

```
<mat-slider class="slider-left"></mat-slider>
<mat-slider class="slider-right"></mat-slider>

.slider-right {
  position: relative;
  left: -128px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26) !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-slider-track-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve that using following code:

```
<mat-slider id="to-slider"></mat-slider>
<mat-slider id="from-slider"></mat-slider>
```

```
#from-slider {
  margin-top: -75px;
}

 ::ng-deep {
  #from-slider {
    .mat-slider-track-fill {
      background-color: GRAY_COLOR;
    }
    .mat-slider-track-background {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  }
  #to-slider {
    .mat-slider-track-background {
      background-color: GRAY_COLOR;
    }
  }
}
```

Just notice that GRAY_COLOR should not have transparency!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this, Angular Material
v17 now supports the range slider in its latest release.
*(It is not available for older versions)*

You can create a range slider like this :

```js
<mat-slider>
  <input matSliderStartThumb>
  <input matSliderEndThumb>
</mat-slider>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview#slider-range